# How to extract text from header tags, wrap in <li> and append to list, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery function to take the visible h3 tags' text and append them to a side menu. I've got the text appearing in the menu correctly, but I cannot strip, then wrap them in the tags I want.

I have included the code below, can anyone see why the wrapping is not working?

```
   function populateRightMenu() {
        //  empty existing menu right-menu-list
        $('#right-menu-list').empty();
        //  get list of h3
        var items = $('h3:visible');
        //  inject into menu
        $(items).clone().unwrap('h3').wrap('<li></li>').appendTo('#right-menu-list');
    }
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ *Remove the parents* - if you're selecting `h3` then `h3.unwrap("h3")` isn't the parent of h3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.wrap()` doesn't return the newly wrapped parent items, it returns the existing items, so using `.clone().wrap().append()` you're appending the clone, not the outer wrap.

You can fix this by selecting the new wrapper:

```
var items = $('h3:visible');
items.clone().wrap('<li></li>').closest("li").appendTo('#right-menu-list');
```

alternatively, wrap the items after appending them

```
items.clone().appendTo('#right-menu-list').wrap('<li></li>');
```

```js
$('#right-menu-list').empty();
var items = $('#source h3');
items.clone().wrap('<li></li>').closest("li").appendTo('#right-menu-list');

$('#right-menu-list2').empty();
var items = $('#source h3');
items.clone().appendTo('#right-menu-list2').wrap('<li></li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="source">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <h3>3</h3>
</div>

<hr/>
<ul id="right-menu-list"></ul>

<hr/>
<ul id="right-menu-list2"></ul>
```

---

While the question is primarily about `wrapp`ing with `li`, there's also the question about *unwrapping* the `h3`.  Because `.unwrap()` unwraps the parents, not the items themselves.  So you effectively want `$("h3").children().unwrap("h3")` - but `.children()` doesn't select *text nodes* - so if your `h3`s are like `<h3>text</h3>` then this won't work (there's no HTML in the question, so this may be ok, or you may be ok adding eg a `span` in the `h3`s.  The easiest method here is to extract the content directly, but this won't clone any events - so it depends on how the `h3` is built

```
$("#right-menu-list").append(items.map(function(i,e) { return "<li>" + $(e).html() + "</li>" }).toArray())
```